# Closable tabs in Angular material

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I've been fiddling with Angular-Material and it does seem pretty slick. One of the issues though, that we're having is the lack of the ability to close a tab using an 'X' button next to the tab's label. This is similar to what any browser tab UI will have to offer.
In the current UI framework we use (Angular Bootstrap UI) you could define the rendering of the tab header to add such a button.
Any ideas on how to implement it with Material's md-tab directive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The docs at: https://material.angularjs.org/#/api/material.components.tabs/directive/mdTab

Say:

> If the label attribute is not specified, then an optional
>    tag can be used to specify more complex tab header
>   markup. If neither the label nor the md-tab-label are specified, then
>   the nested markup of the  is used as the tab header markup.

Why not define your in a  tag?

Comment: Great lead and will be marked as the correct answer. It would be nice to have it built in the md-tab directive as it seems like a basic tab functionality(when needed). [Here's the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PupIBn?p=preview) I've implemented using your advice.